# How to send an ID to the database for searching in callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I have a code snippet in **db.js** as below,

```
exports.asyncGetAllData = function (cb) {
        connection.connect(function(err) {
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM prices WHERE=" + "'" + ID + "'", function (err, result) {
                //console.log("info:" + cb);
                if (err) console.log("Error: " + err);
                else
                {
                    cb(result);
                }
            });
        });
};
```

I want to pass and ID from **app.js** into asyncGetAllData function in **db.js**. The following code snippet is in app.js

```
app.get('/test/getPriceTrend/:parameter', function(req, res) {
console.log('SERVER::testGetPriceTrend');
console.log(req.url);
var str=req.url;

db_connection.asyncGetAllData(function(data) {
    var obj = str.split("&");
    var ID = obj[0].split("/")[3];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    res.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    res.writeHead(res.statusCode);
    //The following piece of code will send information from the database
    res.write("hello");
    res.end();
});
```

});

In the above-mentioned code (app.js), I have parsed ID from a get request. I want to send this ID to asyncGetAllData function which resides in db.js. How can I send ID parameter and fetch the result?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just extend the function with an additional argument

```
exports.asyncGetAllData = function (cb, ID) {
    connection.connect(function(err) {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM prices WHERE=" + "'" + ID + "'"  ...
```

And then pass it when you call the function in app.js

```
var str = req.url;
var obj = str.split("&");
var ID  = obj[0].split("/")[3];

db_connection.asyncGetAllData(function(data) {
    ...
}, ID);
```